# Migrate to GeoDjango Points from longitude/latitude?

Tags: django, postgis

Using the Django ORM, Postgres/PostGIS, and Django migrations, how do I convert my existing `longitude` and `latitude` float fields into a single GeoDjango Point field?

I was looking for something like `Location.objects.update(point=(F('longitude'), F('latitude')))`.

Comment: wait are you asking how to actually write a migration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming you have an object with a PointField like

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    point = models.PointField(geography=True, default='POINT(0.0 0.0)') #or similar
```

you could just do:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

for l in Location.objects.all():
    l.point = Point(x=l.longitude, y=l.latitude, srid=4326)
    l.save()
```

or this single statement should work if you really want a single update (untested though):

```
Location.objects.all().update(point=Point(x=F('longitude'), y=F('latitude'), srid=4326))
```

NOTE: though I've used GeoDjango and postgis quite a bit, I'm by no means an expert in it. I don't know what the PointField does under the hood... if it's creating a relationship then it will not work in a single statement as Django doesn't allow updating across tables in update statements, you must loop over, if it's just formatting the data then it should work fine... I did a little research and it seems like the srid is the only relationship, so this should be fine because creating static relationships IS fine in an update statement.

drawing from the answer you posted above, you would simply write that as a function (named set_points for instance) in your migration file and then add  this in the operations section of your migration to run it:

```
migrations.RunPython(set_points),
```

migration writing reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/writing-migrations/

Comment: Thanks!  Upvoted cause it works, but if you have a lot of these, looping over them and saving one at a time is much slower than solutions using a single `update`.

Comment: it's a one time operation so the optimization feels extra, but too each his own

Comment: Tell that to the dozen developers who have to run this thing on a dev database of a few million geo points... it can take your dev environment out of commission for a significant period of time.

Comment: well then I see no reason your original query can't be run inside a migration with a few tweaks? does Location.objects.all().update(point=Point(x=F('longitude'), y=F('latitude'), srid=4326)) not work for some reason?

Comment: @ScottStafford Indeed, is there any other method available that can do this instantly? All developers know that a wrong structural choice, costs a lot when trying to solve it afterwards. I am feeling lucky that I can get away with it by only leaving a box running a few hours overnight.

Comment: I mean if you need to update all the records then you need to update all the records.  You can try batching, or writing your own SQL to do this but I'd feel safer letting the library handle it unless you're especially good at postgis / spatial geometry programming.  I am not, I'm just a web dev who's needed to migrate to postgis before, so I used my original function and ran it over night.  I didn't even do it in a migration, I just wrote it as a command and included it in that deployment script along with the usual migrate and collectstatic commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487182/237091.  Will still prefer a solution that doesn't drop to SQL.

Comment: really easy to use that migrations file to run a python function instead of SQL, see my answer.