# GeoDjango, Cordinates from Google maps are getting plotted wrong on leaflet using PointField

Tags: django, google-maps, django-admin, postgis, geodjango

Please help me out in solving this issue.

```py
class RecievingImages(models.Model):
    """Original and Masked Images"""
    name          = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True, primary_key=True)
    cordinate_X   = models.FloatField()
    cordinate_Y   = models.FloatField()
    point         = models.PointField(srid=4326, geography=True, default='POINT(0.0 0.0)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Image Mapping'
```

I have coordinates that I got from google maps API
Example here

```
cordinate_X : 21.2166277
cordinate_Y : 72.7763859
```

Technically, These coordinates are of Gujrat, India
[actual link of the coordinates](https://www.google.com/maps/place/21%C2%B012'59.9%22N+72%C2%B046'35.0%22E/@21.2166277,72.7763859,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d21.2166277!4d72.7763859)

Now to plot on leaflet I converted that into point field with reference to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293443/7999665

```py
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

for l in RecievingImages.objects.all():
...     l.point = Point(x=l.cordinate_X, y=l.cordinate_Y, srid=4326)
...     l.save()
```

Now when I went back to Django admin page it's marking the coordinates wrongly somewhere in Sea

[image: After Conversion of Coordinates into Point Field]

Thanks for your time.

Regards

---

**Update**

After a good amount of googling, I found that there could be an issue of *srid* used that is, google maps might be using '3587' and I have used '4326'
I tried to change this but am getting an error.

```
    raise NotSupportedError('PostGIS only supports geography columns with an SRID of 4326.')
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostGIS only supports geography columns with an SRID of 4326.
```

The database I have used is PostGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your coordinates are swapped. X is longitude, Y is latitude.

Your link shows coordinates here:
21°12'59.9"N 72°46'35.0"E. Google puts latitude first.

Try this:

```
cordinate_X : 72.7763859
cordinate_Y : 21.2166277
```